# OSGi 114 Deployment Admin vs 134 Subsystem Service

Tags: java, osgi

I am looking for a *standard* way of deploying logical units into OSGi platform. My requirements are simple:

- Logical unit can contain or depend on other units, bundles or resources.
- It should be possible to install, uninstall and update any given logical unit
- It should be possible to retrieve logical units and/or their dependencies from a remote repository of some kind (Maven, OBR etc)

I came across these two specs in OSGi 5.0 Compendium: 114 Deployment Admin and 134 Subsystem Service. They both seem to fit at least some of the requirements but I fail to see how they are linked to each other. Are they supposed to play together or these are two completely orthogonal specs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orthogonal. Deployment Admin was originally developed as part of the Mobile Spec. Subsystems was developed as part of the Enterprise Spec.